# How to get an ApplicationServiceHost instance with TFS 2013's Server Object Model?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I spent a lot of time looking how to get an instance of a ApplicationServiceHost with TeamFoundation 12.0 (TFS 2013) using the TFS **Server** Object Model... This class used to be in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.dll within TeamFoundation 10.0. But I don't find how to get it with TeamFoundation 12.0.

I need to use the **Server** Object Model as I want to access the Queued Jobs of TFS (using the method QueryJobQueue of the Server Job Service), a method not available Client side.

Using the Server Object Model of TFS 2010, one could do something like:

```
var applicationHost = new ApplicationServiceHost( 
                Guid.Empty, 
                applicationDatabaseConnectionString, 
                "unused", 
                Path.Combine(toolPath, "Plugins"), 
                "/tfs", 
                true);
```

But I cannot figure out how to do it concretely with the Server Object Model 12.0. According to MSDN, I should get first a TeamFoundationServiceHost (Application or Collection) and use its property [ApplicationServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.teamfoundationservicehost.applicationservicehost.aspx). But how can I get such a TeamFoundationServiceHost programmaticaly ?

Once I can get such an instance, I will use the C# Server OM code sample from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisid/archive/2010/02/15/introducing-the-tfs-background-job-agent-and-service.aspx) to access the job service from a console application. The purpose is to check if any Backup job is running before rebooting the TFS server and give Windows' patches a chance to be applied...

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to know if a backup is running, then you'd probably want to use the client API, not the server API. The server API is intended for plugins such as server side event subscriptions (ISubscriber interface) and custom jobs for the job agent to run.

Unfortunately, as you've probably found, the client API can list all the job definitions and you can look at job history, but you can't see the job queue itself or wether a job is running.

So, what to do?

If you just want to know if there are no backups running before you can reboot and you're OK checking things manually you can look at the job agent status via the operations interface by browsing to `http://yourserver:8080/tfs/_oi/`

If you want to detect things via code then it might be worth a look at what calls the Job Queue page is making under the hood using your browser developer tools (i.e. the F12 tools). You'll see calls to the `http://yourserver:8080/tfs/_oi/_monitoring/GetJobQueue` API. If you call that API via code you should be able to see if there are any InProgress jobs.

Note: the API is undocumented so you might need to experiment a little to determine the right parameters for the call.

Comment: Thx a lot ! I appreciate your suggestions. I will investigate the second one, as I want to call this from a script. I would possibly add a last option: call my code from a server side event handler :D. I used to wrote a lot of handlers for check-in events. I will look what I could imagine here (between undocumented API's and hijacked processes, no idea what's the worst) :D